# What does this pointer-heavy C code do?

Tags: c, pointers

Could someone explain to me what should two following lines do:

```
s.httpheaderline[s.httpheaderlineptr] = *(char *)uip_appdata;
++((char *)uip_appdata);
```

This is taken from uIP code for microcontrollers.

s - structure
httpheaderline - http packet presented as a string
httpheadrlineptr - integer value
uip_appdata - received ethernet packet (string)

If some more info is needed please let me know.

BTW. Eclipse is reporting an error on the second line with message *Invalid lvalue in increment* so I'm trying to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: It copies a character from the packet and advances the packet pointer to the next character, in a way that doesn't seem to be valid according to the C standard.

Comment: The error message comes from the fact that casts on the left side of an assignment statement are not allowed. I think this should be okay: `uip_appdata = ((char *)uip_appdata) + 1;`

Comment: I thought it is doing something like that, but this `*(char *)` is confusing me a bit?

Comment: You can try to fix it like this `++(*((char **)&uip_appdata));` though a complete rewrite of the fragment is in order.

Comment: If uip_appdata is an `array` or `const` or a pointer (to an object) that handles only alligned addresses, you may get problems. (looks like it is a pointer of type `unsigned int`)

Comment: `*(char *)` means "dereference the following value interpreted as a char pointer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention behind first line is to grab a character pointed to by `uip_appdata`:

```
*(char *)uip_appdata
```

casts `uip_appdata` to `char*`, then dereferences it, thus taking the first character.

The second line tries to increment `uip_appdata`. The trouble is, it does not do it properly, because results of a cast cannot be incremented "in place".

Here one way of doing it that works:

```
char *tmp = uip_appdata;
uip_appdata = ++tmp;
```

With this code fragment the compiler can take care of converting between pointer types in cases when the platform requires it.

Here is a [demo of this concept](http://ideone.com/2eUYhC) on ideone.